# how to remove string with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have tried too many available solutions on stackoverflow and from other websites but none of them is working for me. I have a very little issue that currently I have my URL like this;

1. http://localhost:81/www/bootstrap/info.php?lookup=203.130.20.126
2. http://localhost:81/www/bootstrap/ranges.php?lookup=203.130.20.0-203.130.20.0

and I want to remove .php?lookup= from the URL and need to add / before the last string like;

1. http://localhost:81/www/bootstrap/info/203.130.20.126
2. http://localhost:81/www/bootstrap/ranges/203.130.20.0-203.130.20.0

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^/]+).php?lookup=?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
and
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$.php?lookup=/$1 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/www/bootstrap/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www/bootstrap/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (/www/bootstrap/[^.]+)\.php\?lookup=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?lookup=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for the time. Well I have update this as it is and it move my website to
http://localhost:81/www/bootstrap/index.php

Comment: and if I directly paste above mentioned URLs, nothing happens. they work as they working before.

Comment: Yes, This direct link gives 404 Error and .htaccess is located under http://localhost:81/www/bootstrap/

Comment: I have updated this code but still its working on same behavior.  1. If I submit a form, it redirects now to home page. and If i direct open any URL from above mention list, it works fine but if I type http://localhost:81/www/bootstrap/info/203.130.20.126 , it gives 404 error

Comment: Yes, I just added "This is Only the Test" and I face Internal Server Error of miss configuration :(

Comment: Check my updated code and reenter `http://localhost:81/www/bootstrap/info.php?lookup=203.130.20.126` in browser. It should be redirected to `http://localhost:81/www/bootstrap/info/203.130.20.126`

Comment: sorry for too much late reply and yes its working but I need to add my controller name now :( like
http://localhost:81/www/bootstrap/controller_name/info/203.130.20.126
Really Thanks for your All Help

Comment: In the first `RewriteRule` line change that to `RewriteRule ^ controller_name/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]`